# How do I set Excel column types and formatting?

Tags: delphi, excel, delphi-xe2, quantumgrid

I'm exporting data from a CxDBGrid to an Excel file.
I'm able to create the file and copy data in it, but I'm having real trouble with the column formatting. Since I'm pulling the data from a DB I'd like the spreadsheet to reflect the type: NUMBER, VARCHAR2,DATE and so on.
I visually created a macro, went to look for the VBA code, and replicated it in the Delphi project:

```
sheet.Columns[K+2].NumberFormat := '0,000'; //Number
sheet.Columns[K+2].NumberFormat := '@'; //Text
sheet.Columns[K+2].NumberFormat := 'm/d/yyyy'; //Date
```

Number formatting works ok most of the times, but the other two don't.
When I open the generated file, the text columns show up as type "Custom" and every cell displays "-64". If I go to edit a cell, the correct value is actually there.
Date is another issue: the DB's format is dd/mm/yyyy and if I feed it to Excel as-is, it gets all messed up. I tried setting the correct format, but then Excel doesn't recognize it.

Any clues?

I'm also setting column width. That works flawlessly.

Comment: I assume when you say cxDbGrid you are referring to the Developer Express components. If so, are you exporting to Excel using the ExportGridToExcel() procedure provided by Developer Express?

Comment: I have tried that but it has problems with setting the data type. That's why I want to do things manually

Comment: I use ExportGridToExcel() a number of places without any problems related to data types or formatting on export. Without seeing your code it's difficult to figure out why it didn't work for you. Rather than go to the trouble of writing your own export, I'd ask in the Developer Express support site if they can help you. Their support is great and usually they can help you with a solution pretty quickly.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the assigned values are Unicode strings. Try this:

```
sheet.Columns[K+2].NumberFormat := AnsiChar('@');
sheet.Columns[K+2].NumberFormat := AnsiString('m/d/yyyy');
```

Comment: OMG, this really helped me! Fantastic!

Comment: I was a bit confusing because number seemed to set to `Number` but `@` set the format to text. Awesome

Answer (score 3):

You haven't said "how you are doing things manually" which means people have to completely guess what you're doing.  So here's my wild guess:

1. If I assume you're using the Express Spreadsheet component from Developer Express
   I have estensive experience with this component. It does not support arbitrary numeric formats. It supports a "money" format (0.00) with exactly two decimal places. It does not support three or one, or any other number of decimal places.
   If so, this is a known by-design issue in the Express spreadsheet.
2. If by manually you mean that "sheet" as you show above is an OLE object and you're communicating via OLE Automation to Excel itself, then you should be formatting CELLS either individually or as a range, and not column objects.  I am not sure how column object formats would ever override the cell values, if they do at all.  The formatting of cells is generally a cell by cell matter, and must be dealt with as such.
3. If you really want this to work properly you won't use Excel via OLE automation, you'll get a proper Excel XLS format capable writing library.   I was quite sure that you could get proper results directly from the CX (DevEx) db grid, but I would ask on their forums, not here.  With a regular DB Grid, I'd just use `TJvDBGridExcelExport` which comes in the Jedi JVCL, and which works with the regular VCL DB Grid.