# Delphi: how to write time-string into Excel cell but preserve General NumberFormat

Tags: excel, delphi, formatting, delphi-2009

I have Excel from the client (which generated it from the print-to-Excel function), strange thing is that Excel contains time string '06:15:00' into the cell with the General format. I should create identitcal Excel from the Delphi.

May code is:

```
 FWorksheet.Cells.Item[4, 5].NumberFormat:='';
 FWorksheet.Cells.Item[4, 5].NumberFormat:='06:15:00';
 FWorksheet.Cells.Item[4, 5].NumberFormat:='';
```

But it results into 0.260416666666667 in the General format. I can observe 2 strange scenarious:

1. If I format cell as General, then write 6:15:00, in that case the format is automatically converted to Custom and converting the format to General results in 0.26041666...
2. If I click with mouse into the cell (General: 6:15:00) of the client Excel, then Excel converts the cell format into Custom and subsequent converting into the General of Text also results in 0.26...

So, I should find the way how to write into the General cell the string '06:15:00' and at the same time preserve the General format. It is impossible to generate Delphi code from the recorded VBA macro code, because I can not find the way to compose visual Excel commands so to arrive at this state.

I am using OLE Excel Excel_TLB.

I have found the command sequence in Excel that gives the desired result, this sequence can be recorded as Macro:

```
 Range("O4").Select
 Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
 Range("O4").Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "06:15:00"
 Range("O4").Select
 Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
 Range("O6").Select
```

But my translation of this Macro in the Delphi code:

```
 FWorksheet.Cells.Item[4, 5].NumberFormat:='@';
 FWorksheet.Cells.Item[4, 5].FormulaR1C1:='06:15:00';
 FWorksheet.Cells.Item[4, 5].NumberFormat:='';
```

still produces 0.260...

Comment: Add a leading apostrophe, so enter `'06:15:00`, but then this value will be treated as text.

Comment: There is no leading apostrophe in the client Excel. Client uses Excel in is integrated processes and exact conformance is the must.

Answer (score 2):

The use of `AnsiChar` is the solution:

```
 FWorksheet.Cells.Item[4, 5].NumberFormat:=AnsiChar('@');
 FWorksheet.Cells.Item[4, 5].FormulaR1C1:='06:15:00';
 FWorksheet.Cells.Item[4, 5].NumberFormat:='';
```

Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/24034170/1375882 pointed out that it is really important to use AnsiChar @ here, not UnicodeChar which is provided by Delphi2009 by default.

Comment: I have deleted my last (false) comment once I have realised I have answered [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52056411) - using VBA. In the comments OP said that this method does not work in Excel 2016 - still adds apostrophe, so the exact behavior may be version specific.

Comment: It remains to be understood, why recorded macro uses just '@' without conversion to Ansi. I guess - Excel and Macros are all Unicode and that is why recording of pure '@' may be misleading.