Delphi - How to paste the clipboard contents into Excel using Delphi at runtime
How do I copy the contents of the Windows Clipboard into a Excel Spreadsheet at runtime?
I'm able to open Excel, copy some contents to the Clipboard but unable to copy or paste the Clipboard into Excel at runtime.
Heres a small example thats missing the Clipboard paste into Excel:-
uses  Vcl.Clipbrd, System.Win.ComObj{CreateOLEObject};
var
  xls, wb: OLEVariant;

begin
  try
    // Create the Excel App.
    xls := CreateOLEObject('Excel.Application');
    // Create a WorkBook.  
    wb := xls.Workbooks.Add;

    // Clear the Clipboard.
    Clipboard.Clear;
    // Assign some test text.
    Clipboard.AsText := 'Test Text';

    // Put the Clipboard contents into the Spreadsheet here:-

    // Display Excel
    xls.Visible := True;
  except
    on E:Exception do
    begin
      MessageDlg('Problems.' + E.Exception, mtWarning, [mbOk], 0);
    end
  end;
end;

Thanks

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58285073/delphi-how-to-write-time-string-into-excel-cell-but-preserve-general-numberform

since it's mostly vba check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.paste

As per Excel paste mutiple cellls from clipboard [sic] it should be:
  xls.Visible:= TRUE;
  xls.Range['B1','B1'].Select;  // Something must be selected before.
  xls.ActiveSheet.Paste;  // Insert whatever the clipboard contains (may not be text only).

As you are used by working with Excel manually: you first have to select the target sheet and then the target cell(s) where you want to paste your clipboard content.

You shouldn't use .Select. You can directly use the .Range object without selecting it first. See this post for a discussion of not using .Select when working with Office automation.

@AmigoJack. Thanks for the reply. The "xls.ActiveSheet.Paste;" method works for me after "xls.Visible := True;" I've amended my question to display working solution.

This is not how Stack Overflow works! You're expected to accept answers and not to edit your question afterwards to include a solution yourself. You should have taken the [tour] long ago.

This works for me:-
uses  Vcl.Clipbrd, System.Win.ComObj{CreateOLEObject};
var
  xls, wb: OLEVariant;

begin
  try
    // Create the Excel App.
    xls := CreateOLEObject('Excel.Application');
    // Create a WorkBook.  
    wb := xls.Workbooks.Add;

    // Clear the Clipboard.
    Clipboard.Clear;
    // Assign some test text.
    Clipboard.AsText := 'Test Text';        

    // Display Excel
    xls.Visible := True;

    // Put the Clipboard contents into the Spreadsheet
    xls.ActiveSheet.Paste;
  except
    on E:Exception do
    begin
      MessageDlg('Problems.' + E.Exception, mtWarning, [mbOk], 0);
    end
  end;
end;


How is this not just a copy of my answer? Is it really needed to combine both your question and my answer into a second answer? Why not accepting my answer?

@AmigoJack. Your answer had this line:- xls.Range['B1','B1'].Select;  // Something must be selected before.  The comment part of the line included the word "Must", this is wrong, I've tested my code and does NOT require that line, therefore your answer is not 100% correct, only partially. Posting the working solution is helpful for others, its clear and precise. It saves someone from copying code from multiple pieces of code.

"not required" implies it still works - you now argue like it wouldn't work to begin with, but my code doesn't fail. As a member of 5 years you also should know how to use formatting in comments, especially for code.
